# write inline select query with LINQ to SQl

Tags: linq-to-sql

Pardon if title is improper..

How to write below sql query with linq to sql without dividing it in multiple parts?

```
select BookName,
       Author,
       TotalCopies=(select COUNT(*) 
                    from tbEHBookCopies c 
                    where c.BookID=b.BookID) 
from dbo.tbEHBooks b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by multiple parts. If you mean that it should be on one single query then you could do something like:

```
var allBooks = db.tbEHBooks.Select(x => new 
{
    x.BookName,
    x.Author,
    x.TotalCopies = db.tbEHBookCopies.Select(y => x.BookID == y.BookID).Count()
});
```

Comment: is there any syntax change needed here??For some reason its showing error..the 'BookName','Author' does not exist in current context

Comment: now what does this mean'Non-invocable member 'tbEHBookCopies' cannot be used like a method'??

Comment: I've made an additional change.

Answer (score 1):

Using query syntax joining and grouping.  Linq-sql is just a little different when it comes to grouping.  The nice thing about this syntax is that it is easy to join in more tables.  And it looks more like a SQL query only the "from" comes first, and the "select" comes last.

```
var bookQry = from b in db.tbEHBooks
              join c in db.tbEHBookCopies on b.BookID equals c.BookID
              group b by b into books
              select new { books.Key.BookName,
                           books.Key.Author,
                           TotalCopies = books.Count() };
```